# Installing Twilio C# api with VS2008

Tags: c#, twilio

I have successfully installed and tested twilio api with C# .Net framework 4.0 using VS2010. I referred to the link https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install which has instructions to install with VS2010/12

Now I have another computer where I have to install twilio C# api with .net framework 3.5 and VS2008. How can I do that ?
I tried to copy the dlls and take reference but it didn't work.
Kindly let me know how can I install twilio api for C# with .net framework 3.5 and VS2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You will likely need to manually download the NuGet package since there is no built in way in VS2008 to do it.  There are a bunch of ways to do this:

- [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/)
- [NuTake Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap?hl=en&gl=GB)
- [NuGet support for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetSupportForVisualStudio2008.aspx)

Once you get the nupack file change its file extension to .zip, extract the contents and locate the folder that contains the .NET 3.5 version of the assemblies.  Then add to your project.

Or you can always [pull the source](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) from Github.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add SMS support to a legacy VS2008 app, and here's an easy way to do it.

1. Use VS2010 or later, create some dummy project, and then use Nuget Package to download Twilio.  It will create a 'packages' folder inside your solution directory.
2. Use VS2008 to open your actual project.
3. Right click on references, select 'Browse' tab, and browse to the packages folder inside your dummy project you obtained in step one.
4. You need to add two references (one for Twilio, and one for RestSharp, which Twilio depends on).  They are located in these two folders:

...\packages\Twilio.4.4.1\lib\3.5\Twilio.Api.dll

...\packages\RestSharp.105.2.2\lib\net35\RestSharp.dll

The versions I specify above are targetting .NET 3.5